# Detecting line breaks in textarea

Tags: php, html

I have a script in PHP that should be able to detect the number of line breaks from an POSTed value coming from an HTML Textarea.

Basically, i just `substr_count()` my POSTed value against a PHP character supposed to represent the line break character.

I tried a lot of values : `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, `"\r"`, PHP_EOL, `"^M"`, `"\p"`... (notice the double quotes ! ;) )

I can't figure out the character encoding this "break line" in PHP.

When printing my received characters (iterating through posted_string[$i], one line being one iteration), a line break character seems to be :

```
\
r
\
n
```

Comment: you should use nl2br() function

Comment: You mean use nl2br() on my posted value, then trying to detect \n ?

Comment: try $newline = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']); $length=sizeof($newline)-1;echo $length

Comment: @noob This does not work either...

Comment: @vikramsharma This is not working :(

Comment: can you show your code or output

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:

    $newline = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']); 
    $length=sizeof($newline)-1;
    echo $length;
```

have a look at [working demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/uysx-upj8)